# Variable routeprefix configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a pretty big application in MVC .NET 4.6.1.
This project is like an ERP, with a lot of custom routes and ajax calls.

I need to add a route prefix which will represent the "environment" of the application.

So I want to prefix all my routes with an "env" parameter like this :

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{env}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, env = "mat" }
         );
```

Then I will have to access this route parameter "OnRequest", so I can change the environment when I call my data layer on each request.

```
  protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // Here I can get the env route value and change the current selectedEnvironment
        // context.RouteData.Values;    
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
```

I want to know if this is possible at all without rewriting all my controller's actions methods and adding this "env" parameter everywhere.
(areas are not a good choice too)

Like this :

```
[RoutePrefix("{env:string}/medias")]
public class MediasController : Controller {

    [Route("", Name="GetEntiteByCode")]
    [SiteAuthorization]
    public EntiteViewModel GetByCode(string env, string code)
        => CreateGetRequestResponse(() => Service.Get(env, code));
```

Comment: So do you want the same application to answer urls like "dev/medias" and "prod/medias"? Seems like a weird way of implemeting different kinds of environments? Usually different environments are published to different servers and accessed like mydevsite.com/medias and mysite.com/medias

Comment: @Esko Exactly ! I'm looking for a solution to avoid publishing multiple times my app and having 3 applications running for the same site.

Comment: I would highly discourage you from doing this. What if you modify some code that works in your local, but doesn't when you deploy it? You break all three of your environments.

Comment: try to create a base class for all controllers that you have, and move your logic there

Answer (score 0):

I found out a way to do it, not sure if it's best practice but it seems to work just fine. I noticed that the `MapMvcAttributeRoutes` method can take an `IDirectRouteProvider` as an argument.

It took a bit of guesswork but I was able to write a class that derives from the framework's `DefaultDirectRouteProvider` and overrides the GetRoutePrefix method:

```
public class CheckoutPrefixRouteProvider : DefaultDirectRouteProvider
{
    protected override string GetRoutePrefix(ControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
    {
        return "Checkout/" + base.GetRoutePrefix(controllerDescriptor);
    }
}
```

I can then use this new class as follows:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(new CheckoutPrefixRouteProvider());
    }
}
```

I hope this is helpful :)

Comment: Hello
Thanks for your answer !
I tried that but it won't work on my project, the routeprovider is never called. 
Also, is this a solution to have a prefix that is a parameter/variable ? I want to have a prefix that will be a enum : MAT/SAV/PROD  , not a fixed prefix

Comment: have you faced any specific errors or not?

Comment: No error at all